# Custom fonts in app

Tags: c#, c++, xna, windows-phone-8, monogame

In my app i want to add feature to use custom fonts.

User choose font from list on my server, download and use it in app.

How to do the part of the app that will render font?
How to do it in an app that does not use the xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task you're about to embark on is probably going to involve a fair amount of code because the characters in the font will need to be rendered to a texture first before they can be rendered as part of a SpriteBatch.

Typically, this works in XNA by going through the content pipeline. You select a font file and setup the font properties in XML, then the content content pipeline compiles this information into an xnb resource which can be loaded and rendered. The problem is, it all happens at compile time and therefore it's going to be hard to do at run-time.

Reference: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/drawing-text-with-spritefonts

An alternative method is to use a tool like BMFont to pre-render your font to a texture and write your own renderer. I wrote a tutorial once using this technique. However, it's much the same thing but you're replacing the XNA content pipeline with the BMFont tool.

http://www.craftworkgames.com/blog/tutorial-bmfont-rendering-with-monogame/

With this in mind, if you want to achieve this you'll probably need to write your own code to render each font to a texture after you've loaded it at run-time. You'll also need to keep track of the rectangle on the texture for each glyph as you're loading in the font. To save texture space and support larger font sizes you might also need to consider texture packing and excluding certain characters.